# Simplifying a quotient group $\frac{\mathbb Z(\{e_1,e_2,...,e_{n+1}\})}{\mathbb Z(\{e_1,2e_2-e_1,...,2e_{n+1}-e_n\})}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

Here, $\mathbb Z(S)$ denotes the free Abelian group generated by set $S$.

I want to simplify the quotient group $\frac{\mathbb Z(\{e_1,e_2,...,e_{n+1}\})}{\mathbb Z(\{e_1,2e_2-e_1,...,2e_{n+1}-e_n\})}$.

I noted that $e_k\equiv 2^{n-k+1}e_{n+1}$ for all $k: 1\le k\le n-1$ but not sure how to go from here.

Apparently, the answer is $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \oplus (\mathbb Z/2^2\mathbb Z)\oplus...\oplus (\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_k:=e_k-2^{n-k+1}e_{n+1}$ for all $k: 1\le k\le n,$ and $f_0:=e_1-f_1=2^ne_{n+1}.$ Our quotient group is
$$\frac{\Bbb Z(\{f_1,\dots,f_n,e_{n+1}\})}{\Bbb Z(\{f_0,f_1,\dots,f_n\})}\cong\frac{\Bbb Z(\{e_{n+1}\})}{\Bbb Z(\{f_0\})}\cong\Bbb Z/2^n\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand why the subgroup is generated by $e_k-2^{n-k+1} e_{n+1}$ and $e_1$. Can you please explain that? I think it is generated by $2e_{k+1}-2^{n-k+1} e_{n+1}$  and $e_1$.

Comment: As you correctly noted, $e_k\equiv 2^{n-k+1}e_{n+1}$ for all $k: 1\le k\le n-1,$ but you forgot $k=n.$ These $n$ congruences are equivalent to the $n$ congruences $e_n\equiv2e_{n+1},e_{n-1}\equiv2e_n,\dots,e_1\equiv2e_2$ originally given (together with $e_1\equiv0,$ which I leave unchanged).

Comment: I don't understand how you got $Z/2^n Z$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now :-).

Comment: Same method in [Christoph's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174585/quotient-of-a-free-mathbbz-module/174609#174609). I fully agree with his first sentence: "The computational way to calculate this kind of quotient uses the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form). However, for small modules we can easily figure out a change of basis that immediately reveals the quotient structure."

Answer (score 2):

A systematic way to solve this kind of problems, is by writing it as the cokernel of the map

$$\Phi:\mathbb Z^{n+1}\to\mathbb Z^{n+1}$$

where the matrix representation of $\Phi$ in the basis $e_1,\ldots,e_{n+1}$ is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 &  2 & -1 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 &  0 &  2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   \vdots &   && \ddots &&& \vdots \\
                   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 2 & -1 \\
                   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 2 
   \end{pmatrix}$$

and then computing its [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which is

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 &  1 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   0 &  0 &  1 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
                   \vdots &   && \ddots &&& \vdots \\
                   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
                   0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & 2^n 
   \end{pmatrix}$$

from which the same result as Anne Bauval's follows.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-).