# Determining the structure of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}^3/K$, with $K=\langle (2,1,-3),(1,-1,2)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Well, this is the exercise:

> Determine the structure of $\mathbb{Z}^{(3)}/K$ where $K$ is generated by $f_1=(2,1,-3)$, $f_2=(1,-1,2)$.

Looking at the proof of the fundamental structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID, I tried to find the normal form of 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 &-3 \\
1 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then,  by multiplications with elementary matrices (in each $\rightarrow$ I multiplied $A$ by elementary matrices, so A is equivalent with all these matrices)
$$
A \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 \\
2 & 1 &-3
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 3 & -7
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 & 0\\
0 & 3&-7
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
0&3&-1
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 \\
0&-1&3
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0\\
0&-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I got that
$$
A\sim \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But, I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76791/what-does-it-mean-here-to-describe-the-structure-of-this-quotient-module). So, Where is my mistake? And, I'd appreciate if someone could explain me the reasoning in the above link.

**EDIT**: I have to add that, if my calculations were correct, I still don't get how can be that both invariant factors were units. I think (please correct me If I'm wrong) that if both were units implies that $\mathbb{Z}^3/K$ would be isomorphic to $\{0\}$, and that can not be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right and something in the calculation in the linked question went wrong.

Observe that $A$ has a $2\times2$ minor
$$
\left|\begin{array}{rr}2&-3\\1&2\end{array}\right|=7.
$$
The g.c.d. of the $2\times2$ minors is equal (up to sign) to the product of two smallest invariant factors. But $3\nmid7$, so $3$ cannot appear in the Smith normal form, i.e. the other poster (or I!) made an error.

---

The role of the diagonal entries in the Smith normal form appears in the theorem (aka *the stacked bases theorem*): Assume that $R$ is a PID and $M\subseteq N$ are finitely generated free $R$-modules. Let $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ be a basis of $N$, $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m, m\le n,$ be generators of $M$. Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the $m\times n$ matrix $A$ determined by the equations¹
$$
v_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}u_j.
$$
If the diagonal entries of the Smith normal form of $A$ are $d_1\mid d_2\mid\cdots\mid d_m$, then there exist bases (these are the stacked bases) $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ of $N$ and $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m$ of $M$ such that
$$
f_i=d_ie_i\quad\text{for all $1\le i\le m$}.
$$
Consequently
$$
N/M\cong (R/d_1R)\oplus (R/d_2R)\oplus\cdots (R/d_mR)\oplus R^{n-m}.
$$

---

¹In other words, the $k$-th row of the matrix $A$ is the element $v_k$ written in the basis given by $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$ (just like a [coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) in the context of vector spaces).

---

There is a proof of this result in at least Jacobson Basic Algebra I, and probably at most other textbooks. It does follow relatively easily from the characterization of Smith normal form.

In your case this implies that
$$
\mathbb{Z}^3/K\cong \mathbb{Z}/(1\cdot\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathbb{Z}/((-1)\cdot\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathbb{Z}^{3-2}\cong\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: So, what does it mean here that the invariant factors of $A$ were both units ?(in the case that my calculations were right) I'm not sure, but I think that If I were right then $M$ would be isomorphic to $\{0\}$, and that can not be

Comment: What Smith Normal Form does is: a basis change. Thus, the calculation shows that $K$ is represented by $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ up to basis change. Then you can conclude that in terms of this modified basis $\mathbb{Z}^3/K\simeq  \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/\{0\} \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @i707107, I almost get your answer, but when you say "$K$ is represented by $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ I get lost. What I understand from your comment is that, exists $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ basis for $\mathbb{Z}^{(3)}$ and $\{f_1,f_2\}$ generators of $K$ such that $$f_1=1\cdot e_1,\ f_2=-1 \cdot e_2$$ and from here you conclude your first comment.

Comment: What do you think about my **EDIT**, that's why I think there's something wrong with my result.

Comment: @JuanPablo: Sorry about leaving that bit out (it was very late here when I first posted). Here the rank of the bigger module is three, but we only have two invariant factors. We need to "append enough many zeros to the list of invariant factors as needed". My edit is trying to make this precise.